# How to have separate log files for every balancer member in load balancer?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, httpd

I am using proxyPass in my Apache v2.2 along with load balancing and have 3 load balancer members. How can I get separate log files for each access made through the balancer member?
For example 3 balancer members and 3 log files.

```
# Enable forward proxy
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember https://10.0.1.210:443
    BalancerMember https://10.0.2.136:443
    BalancerMember https://10.0.3.124:443
 # Set counting algorithm to more evenly distribute work:

</Proxy>

# Enable reverse proxy
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```